# How to create php shortcode with dynamic link?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, elementor

I'm having some trouble creating a WordPress shortcode so I can place it under my Elementor page templates.

```
// Shortcode to output custom PHP in Elementor
function luxis_ics_endpoint( $atts ) {
    return '<a href="'.<?php echo get_feed_link("calendar"); ?>?id=<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>"> Download .ics </a>';
        
}
add_shortcode( 'my_elementor_php_output', 'luxis_ics_endpoint');
```

So the return, I don't know how to properly write it so that it can take those PHP code and generate a link in the shortcode for me to use at frontend.

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: If you want to add it to elementor as a "widget" you need to write some extra code to tell elementor about the shordcode and its settings. There is some information about this in the [elementor developers documentation](https://developers.elementor.com/creating-a-new-widget/) to get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks right. You need to `echo` the function- not `return` in this case.